how to access mesh Properties in React-three-Fiber
I want to know how I can access properties of a mesh using react-three-fiber.
the basic idea should be :
const planeRef = useRef<Mesh>(null);

useFrame(() => {
   if(planeRef.current) {
    //@ts-ignore
    planeRef.current.material.opacity += 0.1
}    

})
However, I cannot access nor can I manipulate the values of planeRef.current.material.opacity.
is there any solution to this ?

Does this answer your question? react-three-fiber opacity animation with useRef does not work

no, it is another question from myself
